# fpdf single output with multiple images

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, cfpdf

How do you output all images in a directory to the same pdf output using fpdf.  I can get the last file in the folder to output as a pdf or output multiple pdfs for each image, but not all images in the same pdf like a catalog.  I'm sure it is the for loop but can't sort it out properly.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
from PIL import Image
import glob
import os


# set here
image_directory = '/home/User/Desktop/images/'
extensions = ('*.jpg','*.jpeg','*.png','*.gif')


# set 0 if you want to fit pdf to image
# unit : pt
margin = 10

imagelist=[]
for ext in extensions:
    imagelist.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(image_directory,ext)))

pdf = FPDF(unit="pt", format=[width + 2*margin, height + 2*margin])
pdf.add_page()
cover = Image.open(imagePath)
width, height = cover.size

for imagePath in imagelist:
    pdf.image(imagePath, margin, margin)
    destination = os.path.splitext(imagePath)[0]
pdf.output(destination + ".pdf", "F")
```

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why fpdf was not grouping the iteration of image files as a single PDF output but img2pdf accepted a list of file names worked very nicely.

```
import img2pdf

imagefiles = ["test1.jpg", "test2.png"]

with open("images.pdf","wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(imagefiles))
```

Comment: Works Great! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to start a new page for every picture in the beginning of the for loop and end with writing everything to the PDF.

```
pdf = FPDF()
imagefiles = ["test1.png","test2.png"]
for one_image in imagefiles:
   pdf.add_page()
   pdf.image(one_image,x,y,w,h)
pdf.output("out.pdf")
```